# These results on my Android tablet's HWUI profiler are acceptable for video content?

Tags: android, hwui

I turned on GPU/HWUI Rendering Profiler on my new P11 Pro gen 2 8gb tablet to see how well it can run Disney+ and video content after seeing occasionally lag spikes on screen. Despite the pretty good hardware specs there is a lot of single and double size bars that goes over the green line and even the red line: [graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BTbH.jpg)
[graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha0EG.jpg)

I checked the ram and cpu usage, I thought it may be too high but they are good, cpu is max 88% usage, ram is 5-6gb. I tested hbo, netflix, disney to see if its only the app problem but got the same or similar results with the graph bars. Also read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/inspect-gpu-rendering) page about the graphs but couldnt really understand what results are good or bad for watching video content.